# UIkit elements can't see in overlaySKScene for AR

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, uikit, scenekit, arkit

I making some simple AR app with interfaces using overlaySKScene.

In viewDidLoad, I applied overlay scene in main ARSCNView(OverlayScene is my class inherited SKScene).

```
self.sceneView.overlaySKScene = [[OverlayScene alloc] initWithSize:self.sceneView.bounds.size];  
self.sceneView.overlaySKScene.delegate = self;
```

Then, I added UIkit button in OverlayScene init.

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];  
[button setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
button.layer.position = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 200);  
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

But, that button didn't appear on screen.
When I added sprite node in this scene, it worked.

Is there other method for it or bug?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OverlayScene`'s `init` isn't really an appropriate place to do that, as `self.view` will equal `nil` because when a scene is initialize it has yet to be added to the view hierarchy. A better choice might be the `SKScene` lifecycle method `- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view;` like:

```
- (void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    [super didMoveToView:view];
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];  
    [button setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];  
    button.layer.position = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, 200);  
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: True. Also note, though, that your `UIButton` isn't at all related to the overlay `SKScene`'s visual content, it just happens to be managed by your `SKScene` subclass. If you aren't using SpriteKit content for your UI overlay, you don't need `overlaySKScene` — you can just put UIKit controls on top of your AR view.

Comment: Very much agree with rickster.

Comment: @rickster any thoughts on why overlaySKScene isn't working? answers to similar questions haven't helped, and the code snippet is so simple -- unclear why it's not working!